# Cannot select any list item from dropdown in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Here is code.  I am trying to select Michael W Baber. Receive error of Element is not displayed.

```
<div id="ext-gen1242" class="x-combo-list-inner" style="width: 324px; height: 110px;">
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Harold W Benton,15,30143</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item x-combo-selected">Michael W Baber,20,13222</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Michael Pfeifer,20,31294</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Staci D Bartels,20,32703</div>
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Stanly C McAfee,20,06136</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ummm... That's not a select list.

Comment: could you please share your code

Comment: Here is my code:   WebElement droplist1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-combo-list-inner']"));    
 droplist1.sendKeys("Michael W Baber,20,13222");
 droplist1.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

Answer (score 2):

Here is the help code for selecting list items:
First, you have to use Select Class from package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.

Then create the object of Select class and use it's method to access dropdown item, the methods to access the dropdown elements are:

1)`selectByVisibleText(Using Text of dropdown item)`

2)`selectByIndex(Select the option at the given index)`

3)`selectByValue(Select all options that have a value matching the argument. That is, when given "India" this would select an option like: <option value="India">Bar</option>)`

The example code is given below:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("country"))).selectByVisibleText("India");
```

The above code will select "India" from the country list.

Comment: Thank you.  However, I cannot get the element identified.  There id changes nor do I see a  css selector?  What are your suggestions?

Comment: Also there is not a select in the list anywhere to use the Select class.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

After the list is displayed, hover to the item then click it

```
WebElement listItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Michael W Baber')]"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                action.build();
                action.moveToElement(listItem)
                    .click();
                action.perform();
```

Comment: I was on it for a month and was not able to select from <list>. This helped me to achieve it. HATS OFF to you.